# Monitor receives NO SIGNAL after moving computer/changing resolution; I've tried all suggestions on the internet to no avail

Tags: graphics-card, display, windows-vista, dell-xps

***Specs***

**Computer:** Dell XPS 420

- OS: Windows Vista (Not sure 32-bit or 64-bit)
- Motherboard: Dell BTX motherboard
- CPU: 2.4GHz Intel Core 2 Quad Q6600
- RAM: 2GB (not sure)
- Graphics: GeForce 8800 GTX

**Monitor:** ASUS VS278Q-P

Story:
Been missing having a nice old desktop since college has shifted me to use primarily laptops, so decided to move my old PC from home to my apartment.

1. PC was working previously at home with no issues.
2. Monitor (ASUS VS278Q-P) newly purchased a few days ago.
3. When I first hooked up the PC to the Monitor, it worked, but resolution was UGLY. So I changed it.

   - When I first connected it to the monitor, it had been defaulted to 1024x600.
   - I changed the resolution to 1366x768. For some reason the PC did not display the option for 1920x1080, the monitor's native resolution.
4. After changing resolution, I figured I wanted to reformat the computer since it had years of junk on it anyways. After I turned it off, that's when the computer *no longer outputs signal to monitor*.
5. Because of **4**, I can not see/access Safe Mode (F8), BIOS (F2), or Alternative Boot (F12)

I have searched online endlessly for the past 2 days, and I've been trying everything that everyone has been suggesting:

- Reset CMOS. Have both pulled battery and used CMOS jumper.
- Took out RAM to see if motherboard beeps upon startup. (Yes)
- Reseated all components.
- Unplugged computer, pushed power button for 5 minutes (power cycling)
- Unplugged all components except for CPU, RAM, HD, Video Card

I'm getting pretty frustrated at this point, and don't know what else to do. I feel like it shouldn't be a hardware issue, since it literally worked when I first tried it, then stopped working 15 minutes later. I don't really want to buy another computer, I bought my monitor because I figured, "Hey, I have a pretty decent computer back home which I can use to just do my school programming and stuff.", NOT because I want to have a gaming rig or anything.

Other information:

- Monitor works flawlessly when connecting my laptops.
- PC has no mobo onboard-display port
- Connecting PC to monitor in this fashion: PC(only has 2 DVI ports)->DVI-HDMI Adapter->Monitor(HDMI port)[Only has HDMI, Displayport, and VGA)
- All fans in computer spinning, components seem to run.
- When pressing F8 for Safe Mode, there's no signal on the monitor still, but I do suddenly hear a bunch of *beep*ing if I hold down F8. I searched online, and found this may just be "buffer overflow", but idk..

Any other suggestions??

Comment: Try different PC to monitor connections.  Try both DVI ports.  One of those DVI ports will output VGA (usually the top one); do you still have the DVI-VGA dongle (and a VGA cable) to make a VGA connection to the monitor?

Comment: I've tried both DVI ports.
I don't have a DVI-VGA dongle, but I guess I can buy one.

Answer (score 0):

You know the computer works and you know the monitor works. I think the graphics card is bad. Can you swap it to check?

Comment: *"I think the graphics card is bad."* -- That's not a reasonable conclusion, but rather just a hypothesis that needs testing.  I.E. you think that the graphics card *may be* bad.  More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Is it that likely that the graphics card could have been damaged in that timeframe though? It was literally working, then I 

 1. changed resolution
 2. turned off computer
 3. moved the computer from the right of my desk to the left of my desk
 4. turned it back on

I understand that my components are really old, but is are they that likely to fail?

Comment: Doesn't matter how likely the failure.  At this point the GPU is a possible point of failure given the evidence.  It is simpler and more prudent to decide what to do after testing the GPU, than to continue to assume that it is fully functional.  If the event has occurred, then probability (to predict if the event will occur) is just for academic discussion.  E.G. did you test both DVI ports?

Comment: @sawdust That's true. Sorry, I think I just knew myself but my cheap self was in denial hahaha.. All the cheap GPUs I can afford are not like that 8800GTX my spoiled child-self was able to have his parents buy!